# PhpStorm - how to put cursor in secondary position in live templates

Tags: phpstorm

this is live template code :

```
<nav class="$END$"></nav>
```

when i type nav and hit tab above code happen and cursor is between class double quotes because i need to type class name first (its working up that level), then when i press tab key, the cursor has to come between the tags.

but anyway this doesnot work as it is. cursor come to END variable point . thats fine. but when i press tab key, indent happen within class. cursor is not coming between nav tags

Comment: Please provide a better example and do not mix your text with explanation. But generally speaking -- it's a basic thing and should be working straight away (if you have read the docs). Right now you are using `$END$` 2 times? Any reason why? Do you know what `$END$` means there? (hint: it's one of the few special variables).

Comment: i only use END variable only once at the beginning. i updated the question now. please check again.

Answer (score 0):

never mind. i found a fix. at the beginning i was following the wrong way. below code works for me with tab key.

```
<nav class="$VAR1$">$END$</nav>
```

Comment: Instead of `$VAR2$` you should better use `$END$` -- it's more appropriate. `$VAR2$` in an ordinary variable so it will create a placeholder (a read-bordered area) where IDE expects you to enter some value (of course, you may just tab-out of it without entering anything). `$END$` is a special variable (as per documentation) that denotes where cursor should be placed when ALL variables have been completed so you are free to do anything there without the need to exit placeholder.